# ProgressView not updating in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I know this question asked many times on StackOverflow, But I already tried a lot of suggestions and tricks but not working the methods.

I got a progress update from `SwiftEventBus` and I am trying to update `ProgressView` like the below in UI.

```
SwiftEventBus.onMainThread(self, name: "fileUploadStart") { result in
            self.progress = result?.object as! Float
            self.init()
        }


func init() {
if self.lastProgress != self.progress {
                self.lastProgress = self.progress
                let finalProgress = self.progress / 100.0
                print("===progress===", finalProgress)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.progressBar.setProgress(finalProgress, animated: true)
                    //              self.progressBar.progress = self.progress/100.0
                }
            }
}
```

I am uploading/downloading files from `Google Drive`. When I am login with `Gmail` for the first time, the progress has been not updated only once. If I go back and come to the same screen the `ProgressView` start updating.

I don't know where I did the mistake. Please someone help me to fix this problem.